# How to install Material Design Lite Documentation Offline?

Tags: node.js, docker, material-design-lite

I have some problem while installing a documentation for Material Design Lite locally. I have following a command in [this file](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite):

```
git clone https://github.com/google/material-design-lite
cd material-design-lite
npm install && npm install -g gulp
gulp all && gulp serve
```

When run `gulp all` there is an error:

```
root@c54a089ac69c:/home/material-design-lite# gulp all
[21:18:38] Requiring external module babel-register
[21:18:42] Using gulpfile /home/material-design-lite/gulpfile.babel.js
[21:18:42] Starting 'clean'...
[21:18:42] Finished 'clean' after 106 ms
[21:18:42] Starting 'all'...
[21:18:42] Starting 'lint:aux'...
[21:18:45] 
/home/material-design-lite/gulpfile.babel.js
  136:1  warning  Unexpected 'todo' comment  no-warning-comments
  807:3  warning  Unexpected 'todo' comment  no-warning-comments

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

[21:18:45] Finished 'lint:aux' after 2.39 s
[21:18:45] Starting 'styletemplates'...
[21:18:49] styles all files 1.07 MB
[21:18:49] Finished 'styletemplates' after 4.04 s
[21:18:49] Starting 'styles-grid'...
[21:18:49] Starting 'styles'...
[21:18:49] styles-grid all files 17.77 kB
[21:18:49] Finished 'styles-grid' after 187 ms
[21:18:50] styles all files 714.08 kB
[21:18:50] Finished 'styles' after 1.39 s
[21:18:50] Starting 'styles:gen'...
[21:18:52] Finished 'styles:gen' after 2.36 s
[21:18:52] Starting 'lint:sources'...
[21:18:56] 
/home/material-design-lite/src/mdlComponentHandler.js
  232:49  error  Properties shouldn't be quoted as all quotes are redundant  quote-props
  366:51  error  Properties shouldn't be quoted as all quotes are redundant  quote-props

/home/material-design-lite/src/checkbox/checkbox.js
  123:5  warning  Unexpected 'todo' comment  no-warning-comments

/home/material-design-lite/src/icon-toggle/icon-toggle.js
  119:5  warning  Unexpected 'todo' comment  no-warning-comments

/home/material-design-lite/src/radio/radio.js
  133:5  warning  Unexpected 'todo' comment  no-warning-comments

/home/material-design-lite/src/switch/switch.js
  122:5  warning  Unexpected 'todo' comment  no-warning-comments

/home/material-design-lite/src/tabs/tabs.js
  88:7  warning  Do not use 'new' for side effects  no-new

/home/material-design-lite/src/textfield/textfield.js
  273:11  warning  Unexpected 'todo' comment  no-warning-comments

/home/material-design-lite/src/layout/layout.js
  520:11  warning  Do not use 'new' for side effects        no-new
  570:3   error    Block must not be padded by blank lines  padded-blocks

✖ 10 problems (3 errors, 7 warnings)

[21:18:56] 'lint:sources' errored after 3.59 s
[21:18:56] ESLintError in plugin 'gulp-eslint'
Message:
    Failed with 3 errors
[21:18:56] 'all' errored after 14 s
[21:18:56] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
    An error occured in task 'lint:sources'.
```

But, when I serve it with `gulp serve`, it's run but just displaying this:

[image: Screenshot]

It's Just displaying the files! How to generate offline documentation for material-design-lite? Any ideas? Thanks.

Thank you;

PS:

I run this with on Docker with [NodeJS Container.](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

Material Design Lite Website: https://getmdl.io

Comment: Can you add to your question what's the command you issue to run the docker container?

Comment: Ive awarded the bounty because i tried installing with npm, After clonning the github repo, then i went ahead and typed npm install which installs all dependencies but npm start fails to start

Comment: @GEOFFREY MWANGI please post the errors you get while you `npm start` and check if the **compatible version** of the *node is installed*

Answer (score 1):

I have never try to clone the repo, but with this way i can get the offline docs. Only using wget tools.
`wget -mkEpnp https://getmdl.io`
And voila, you have the copies of website in your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the GitHub issue referenced [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4192)

*You need to checkout with Unix style line endings. This process is detailed in the `README`.*

*Windows users, if you have trouble compiling due to line endings then make sure you configure git to checkout the repository with `lf` **(unix) line endings**. This can be achieved by setting `core.eol`.*

```
git config core.eol lf
git config core.autocrlf input
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

The other error

```
error  Properties shouldn't be quoted as all quotes are redundant  quote-props
```

has been fixed for the versions greater than `mdl-1.1` as mentioned in the issues [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4278)

*Hope it helps! Cheers !*